# How to make a permanent configuration to eth1

Tags: networking, ip

I need to configure eth1 with:

- IP address: 10.5.15.200;
- Netmask: 255.255.255.128;
- MAC address: A2:BB:CC:DD:5:15;
- Gateway: 10.5.15.129.

Mac address must be set up before eth1 is UP. I must use pre-up but i don't know.

Comment: What steps have you tried so far and what were the problems?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by configuring the `/etc/network/interfaces` file in Ubuntu.

Open `/etc/network/interfaces` file in an editor and the add these following lines

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
   hwaddress ether A2:BB:CC:DD:5:15
   address 10.5.15.200
   netmask 255.255.255.128
   gateway 10.5.15.129
```

Here's a tutorial that can help you http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-your-network-card-mac-address-on-ubuntu/

You can check this out for more details 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/interfaces.5.html

Here's a post that has lots of examples if you need a more advanced configuration
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/

Comment: Mac address must be set up BEFORE eth1 starts

Comment: @Alex i have made the changes.

Comment: So I don't need to use pre-up, no?

Comment: No need . Editing this file would configure your lan during boot.

Comment: Note: this may break the output results from `ifconfig`, or `ifconfig -a`. You may want to run `ip address show`.